# Hi guys i m new in salesforce and making tree view on account as parent, contacts as child and task/event as gchild

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, callout, dynamic-visualforce

I have to retrieve in created date sorted manner i m able to retrieve up to task and events but they both came in separate list .I am unable to put both in same list and sort them by recent created  here my code:- HELP!

**Apex Class :**

```
global class treenodes /*implements Comparable*/{
    /* Wrapper class to contain the nodes and their children */

    List<eEventTTask> taskEventList = new List<eEventTTask>();

    public class cNodes
    {

        public List<Contact> parent {get; set;}
        Public Account gparent {get;set;}  
        public List<Task> taskList { get; set; }
        public List<Event> eventList { get; set; }
        public cNodes( Account  gp, List<Contact> p )
        {

            parent = p;
            gparent = gp;  
        }
    }
    /* end of Wrapper class */ 


    Public List<cNodes> hierarchy;

    //taskList = new List<Task>();
    //eventList = new List<Event>();   


    /*    global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) { 
treenodes compareToTree = (treenodes)compareTo; 
if (dat == compareToTree.dat) return 0; 
if (dat > compareToTree.dat) return 1; 
return -1;       
} */

    Public List<cNodes> getmainnodes(){
        hierarchy = new List<cNodes>();
        List<Account> tempparent = [Select Id,Name from Account];
        for (Integer i =0; i< tempparent.size() ; i++){
            List<Contact> tempchildren = [ SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, 
                                          ( SELECT Id, Createddate , Subject FROM tasks ORDER BY Createddate DESC ),
                                          ( SELECT Id, Createddate , Subject  FROM events ORDER BY Createddate DESC )
                                          FROM Contact 
                                          WHERE AccountId =: tempparent[i].Id ];
            //   dat = tempparent[i].CreatedDate;
             // if(tempparent[i].Contacts.Task.id == Account.Contacts.Task.id ){}

            hierarchy.add( new cNodes( tempparent[i], tempchildren ) );
        //    hierarchy.add( new cNodes(taskEventList [ i ],tempchildren) ); 
        }
        for (Integer i =0; i< hierarchy.size() ; i++){


            for (Task t : [Select Subject, WhatId, OwnerId, ActivityDate, LastModifiedDate From Task/* Where whoId =: hierarchy[i].valueOf(cNodes(gp, p))*/]) {
                taskEventList.add(new eEventTTask(t.Subject, t.WhatId, t.OwnerId, t.ActivityDate, t.LastModifiedDate));
            }

            for (Event e : [Select Subject, WhatId, OwnerId, ActivityDate, LastModifiedDate From Event/*  Where whoId =: hierarchy[i].valueOf() */]){
                taskEventList.add(new eEventTTask(e.Subject, e.WhatId, e.OwnerId, e.ActivityDate, e.LastModifiedDate));
            } 

        }
        return hierarchy;
    }
    class eEventTTask {
        public String subject { get; set; }
        public Id whatId { get; set; } 
        public Id ownerId { get; set; }
        public Date activityDate { get; set;}
        public DateTime lastModified { get; set;}

        public eEventTTask(String sub, Id wht, Id own, Date act, Datetime lmd) {
            subject = sub;
            whatId = wht;
            ownerId = own;
            activityDate = act; 
            lastModified = lmd;

        }
    }


    //  hierarchy.sort();

}
```

**VisualForce Page :**

```
<apex:page sidebar="true" controller="treenodes" showheader="true">
<!-- Include the Jquery Script files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.Jtreeview,'Jquerytreeview/jquery.treeview.css')}"/>
    <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Jtreeview,'Jquerytreeview/jquery.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Jtreeview,'Jquerytreeview/jquery.cookie.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Jtreeview,'Jquerytreeview/jquery.treeview.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- End of Javascript files -->
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#tree").treeview({
                collapsed: true,
                animated: "medium",
                control:"#sidetreecontrol",
                persist: "location"
            });
        }) 
</script>
<br/> <br/> <br/>
<!-- Tree -->
<div class="treeheader" style="height:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="sidetreecontrol"><a href="?#"><font style="color:blue;">Collapse All</font></a> | <a href="?#"><font style="color:blue;">Expand All</font></a></div>
<ul id="tree">
    <apex:repeat value="{!mainnodes}" var="parent">
        <li><strong><apex:outputtext style="color:blue;" escape="false" value="{!parent.gparent.Name}"/></strong>
             <ul>
                 <apex:repeat value="{!parent.parent}" var="child">
                    <li><span class="formattextcon"><apex:outputtext style="color:green;" escape="false" value="{!child.LastName}"/></span>
                        <ul>

                            <apex:repeat value="{!child.events}" var="gchildren"  >
                               <li> <span class="formattextcon"> <apex:outputLink target="_blank" value="/{!gchildren.id}">{!gchildren.Subject}</apex:outputLink>  <b>||</b> &nbsp; <apex:outputtext escape="false" style="color:brown;" value="{!gchildren.Createddate}"  />  </span> </li>
                            </apex:repeat>
                            <apex:repeat value="{!child.tasks}" var="gchildren"  >
                               <li> <span class="formattextcon"> <apex:outputLink target="_blank" value="/{!gchildren.id}">{!gchildren.Subject}</apex:outputLink> <b>||</b> &nbsp; <apex:outputtext escape="false" style="color:brown;" value="{!gchildren.Createddate}"  />  </span> </li>
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </ul>       
                    </li>
                 </apex:repeat>  
             </ul>  
        </li>
    </apex:repeat>
</ul>
<!-- End of Tree -->       
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution to the sorting problem is to implement the [Comparable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm) in your wrapper class: a list sort will then automatically make use of the `compareTo`method:

```
class eEventTTask implements Comparable {

    ...

    public DateTime lastModified { get; set;}

    ...

    public Integer compareTo(Object o) {
        eEventTTask that = (eEventTTask) o;
        if (this.lastModified < that.lastModified) return -1;
        else if (this.lastModified > that.lastModified)return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

then:

```
taskEventList.sort();
```

Comment: can u sir please  elaborate how to get task and event in single list without causing 101 too many query error

Comment: @abhisheksharma That is really a separate question. I answered the question you asked and you didn't even upvote that so I'm not inclined to comment further.